# How does "object.new" work? (Does Java have a .new operator?)

Tags: java, syntax, inner-classes

I came across this code today whilst reading [Accelerated GWT (Gupta) - page 151](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=KXBdajKMJGEC&lpg=PR2&ots=w5NJtxR7nS&dq=accelerated%20gwt&pg=PA151#v=onepage&q&f=false).

```
public static void getListOfBooks(String category, BookStore bookStore) {
    serviceInstance.getBooks(category, bookStore.new BookListUpdaterCallback());
}
public static void storeOrder(List books, String userName, BookStore bookStore) {
    serviceInstance.storeOrder(books, userName,    bookStore.new StoreOrderCallback());
}
```

What are those new operators doing there?  I've never seen such syntax, can anyone explain?

Does anyone know where to find this in the java spec?

Comment: +1 for Java syntax I've never seen before either.

Comment: I knew about inner classes, but I use to create them as: `new outer.SomeClass()`

Comment: Oscar that syntax is for creating a new static inner class

Comment: @Ash Kim inner classes can not be static . The correct terminology is static nested class.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

They're **inner** (nested non-static) classes:

```
public class Outer {
  public class Inner { public void foo() { ... } }
}
```

You can do:

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
outer.new Inner().foo();
```

or simply:

```
new Outer().new Inner().foo();
```

The reason for this is that `Inner` has a reference to a specific instance of the outer class. Let me give you a more detailed example of this:

```
public class Outer {
  private final String message;

  Outer(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public class Inner {
    private final String message;

    public Inner(String message) {
       this.message = message;
    }

    public void foo() {
      System.out.printf("%s %s%n", Outer.this.message, message);
    }
  }
}
```

and run:

```
new Outer("Hello").new Inner("World").foo();
```

Outputs:

```
Hello World
```

**Note:** nested classes can be `static` too. If so, they have no implicit `this` reference to the outer class:

```
public class Outer {
  public static class Nested {
    public void foo() { System.out.println("Foo"); }
  }
}

new Outer.Nested.foo();
```

More often than not, static nested classes are `private` as they tend to be implementation details and a neat way of encapsulating part of a problem without polluting the public namespace.

Comment: It's all spelled out here if anyone's hazy on this: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: and also a good discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Comment: @cleutus "More often than not, static inner classes are private" . This is a wrong statement . inner classes can't be static . This should be called as "static nested class". See the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Comment: shouldn't the last code line read `new Outer.Nested().foo();`?

Comment: In my experience, the last paragraph is backwards; inner classes are often private (because they're implementing some interface like `Iterator` that needs privileged access to the top-level class), and static nested classes are data types like command objects or exceptions that apply to one specific context.

Answer (score 4):

`BookListUpdaterCallback` and `StoreOrderCallback` are inner classes of BookStore.

See The Java Tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this syntax before either, but I think it will create an inner class of `BookStore`.