# Behavior of this.new and bare this in inner classes

Tags: java, this, new-operator, inner-classes

I was writing this code:

```
public class GuiSelectionList<T> extends GuiList<SelectableItem> {

    ...

    public void add(T element) {
        list.add(this.new SelectableItem(element));
    }

    public class SelectableItem {
        public T       data;
        public boolean selected;

        public SelectableItem(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

And I saw that my IDE does not complain whether I use:

```
list.add(this.new SelectableItem(element));
```

or

```
list.add(new SelectableItem(element));
```

My question is: Are both the same thing?

Comment: yes; but it's customary to omit `this.` we do `outer.new` only if `outer` is not `this`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are the same.

`something.new InnerClass(...)` is the most general syntax for creating an instance of an inner class, where `something` is an expression that evaluates to a reference to an instance of the outer class (remember that every inner class instance has a reference to an outer class instance).

When the `something.` is omitted, i.e. `new InnerClass(...)`, and you happen to be in an instance method of the outer class, then it implicitly means `this.new InnerClass(...)`, just like how when you write instance variables or method calls without explicitly accessing it through a dot, it implies `this.` (`someInstanceVariable` implicitly means `this.someInstanceVariable`).

Answer (score 2):

They are essentially the same since `SelectableItem` is an **inner, non static class** to `GuiSelectionList` and you're instantiating it from the `GuiSelectionList` class.

See this related [SO question about "object.new"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863157/how-does-object-new-work-does-java-have-a-new-operator).